# C: scanf and program exit

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to learn C programming with some practical exercises. 
This one for example should read 2 series of numbers (days of the month) input by the user.

The problem that I'm having is that after the first serie, that works ok, the program skips the other scanf commands and terminates.

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int f = 0;
   int days1[31];
   int days2[31];
   printf("Insert first serie \n");
   while(scanf("%d",&days1[f])) {
     f++;
   }

   // the following scanf loop is skipped
   f = 0;
   printf("Insert second serie \n");
   while(scanf("%d",&days2[f])) {
     f++;
   }
}
```

thanks

Comment: I just tested it and it does not even go out the first loop, I can just keep entering numbers.

Comment: @moffeltje: Same here.

Comment: try to enter a letter instead of a number, it will exit

Comment: @user3318528 Try to analyze what happens *inside the program* to the letter entered — you'll find out why the second loop doesn't do what you expected. A detailed `scanf` documentation would be helpful.

Comment: you should have some condition that will terminate the while loop when ever you want  like while(scanf("%d",&days2[f])!=0 && f<31) ; else it will go on running

Answer (score 4):

Read documentation of [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). It returns the number of scanned items, and you should keep and test it. It could return -1 on failure (and that is seen as a true value) then don't consume any input. Its `%n` conversion specifier is often useful and not enough known.

So code

```
 while(f < 31 && scanf("%d",&days1[f])>0) f++;
```

But you probably need to end the first series with something which makes `scanf` fail, and then you need to skip that something. You should define and document a convention about that. Let's pretend that you will type a semicolon `;` then you'll code perhaps:

```
  f=0;
  while(f < 31 && scanf("%d",&days1[f])>0) f++;
  if (getchar() != ';') exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  f=0;
  while(f < 31 && scanf("%d",&days2[f])>0) f++;
```

I'm not sure the above work. You might need to care about spaces or empty lines. You could read each individual line with `fgets` or `getline` and parse each line (using `sscanf` or `strtol`).

<sup>Actually, I would recommend declaring a large enough buffer `char buf[256];`, use `fgets` to read a *single* line containing all the number series, then parse that line using `strtol` in a loop and caring about the end pointer given to `strtol`.</sup>

You need to document the input format, at least as comments. You could use [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation for that, then use standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques.

Of course you should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then learn to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). It is a necessary skill to have.

Comment: I read the scanf documentation and saw the different return values, but I thought that after the first failing, you could anyway proceed with another scanf. the scanf return value never resets?

Comment: You can proceed, but after a failure `scanf` don't consume the input.

Comment: this is interesting! thank you for the explanation! i will try to consume the input in another way. thanks!